# Alternative usage, eg. CGPoint to represent a range

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, coding-style

How bad is it to use a built-in object, type or whatever as something it's blatantly not, even if it performs in exactly the way you need? Assuming it's clearly commented what you're doing.

For example, to use a single CGPoint to represent a start and end point on a single line. Should I really be defining my own identical but differently named struct instead?

Edit: OK, using...

```
struct FloatRange {
    CGFloat min;
    CGFloat max;
};
typedef struct FloatRange FloatRange;
```

...instead. Are there no exceptions to the rule?

Comment: Consider using your own 2 letter prefix instead of CG (MHRange?).  If apple ever implements a CGRange (they already have an NSRange I believe). your code will stop compiling.

Comment: Good point :) +1 to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For type safety, you should be defining your own.

Also remember you can't do `someRange.start` or `someRange.end`. Rather, it would be the inscrutable `someRange.x` or `someRange.y`.

Answer (score 3):

Just define your own appropriate structure, even if it has the same constituent types. There is literally zero benefit to abusing a pre-existing structure, but there is a huge hit to readability if you do so.